# Tkinter Entry widget issue

Tags: python, tkinter

Why am I getting this error when trying to insert into an Entry box in Tkinter?

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3085, in insert

    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!toplevel.!labelframe.!entry"
```

This is my code:

_w2.dbEntry.insert(END, "Hello")

I have tried everything, but I cannot understand why. Please advice.

Comment: Wild guess (in the absence of sufficient detail to do anything *but* make a wild guess): you've either called `Tk()` more than once (which causes all sorts of problems), or you've somehow destroyed the Entry (or its enclosing LabelFrame or window) before attempting to insert text into it.

Answer (score 0):

The toplevel or label frame doesn't exist. You haven't shown enough code, but you are either destroying one of those widgets or you never created them prior to inserting text.